# Connection failed: could not find driver, PHP7.1 SqlServer, Windows Server 2012R2, IIS

Tags: php, sql-server, iis

I'm attempting to get PHP 7.1 to connect to an instance of SQL Server on the same network, I get the following error:

> Connection failed: could not find driver

I've downloaded and added both php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll and php_sqlsrv.dll (both nts versions). I have tried both the most recent release of, AND, the pre-release versions that supposedly fix an error with the .dll files not working with PHP 7.1.

Both files have been added in our php.ini file as well.

PHP file that should connect to the DB..

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$serverName = "######";
// $myUser = "#####";
// $myPass = "######^";
// $dbName = "######";

//connection to the database
try {
  $conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=($serverName,53000);port=1433;Database=$dbName", NULL, NULL);
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  echo "Connected successfully";
}
catch(PDOException $e){
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
?>
```

The PHP.ini section currently looks like this:

```
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll
;extension=php_sqlsrv_71_nts.dll
;extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_71_nts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll
;extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_nts.dll
;extension=php_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv.dll
```

php -info only shows odbc under "PDO drivers" - which I believe indicates that it isn't activating.

Have restarted the server multiple times.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried this on the previous version of PHP? or your just starting it on PHP7.1?

Comment: Does it show up here? print_r(get_loaded_extensions()); You did restart the webserver right?

Comment: Just starting on 7.1, and when I run php -info the loaded PDO Drivers only shows ODBC. get_loaded_extensions doesn't show anything related to SQL Server,